# is it possible to add variable value to a select query result php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, pdo

Lets say I have this query:

```
$stmt = $con->_con->prepare("Select id from table", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
}
```

From this I get:

```
[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00"
}]
```

And I want to add another key value pair like :

```
[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00",
    "column": "code1"   
}]
```

From the result I want to add a key `column` with value `code1` this value is dynamic and I want to set it through a condition outside of the select query.
What I tried is manually adding the column in the while loop like:

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
    array_push($rows, array('column' => $column));
}
```

Where `$column = 'code1'` which is depending on a condition. But it give me a result of:

```
[{
    "id": "000060000000000071964708\/17\/201309:55:00"
}, {
    "column": "code1"
}]
```

Which is not a desired output.Also tried doing `Select id,column AS 'code1'...` where I manually try to put the key pair value to be returned as part of select query but it fails and give error in `AS .....`.

> How to get the desired output from the example?
>   I am open to other solution that is better than the ideas I have in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to do this in SQL was almost correct, but the correct form is

```
SELECT 
  id,
  'code1' AS `column`
FROM...
```

to return a static value as a quoted string literal, with a column alias name. So you could query it with the static value as:

```
$stmt = $con->_con->prepare("Select id, 'code1' AS `column` from table", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
```

When fetching, it will return the result in the desired format. However, since the value is dynamic, you can and should use a PDO placeholder for it. It's unclear from the PDO wrapper class you are using where to bind parameters, but the `prepare()` call would be on SQL like

```
// Whatever the source of the dynamic value...
$your_dynamic_value = 'code1';
// Adds :column as a prepared statement placeholder
$stmt = $con->_con->prepare("Select id, :column AS `column` from table", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
```

I have to leave it to you to correctly call `bindParam()` or pass a param array with `[':column' => $your_dynamic_value]` at execution on this unfamiliar PDO wrapper class where the `prepare()` method appears to be doing more than a normal `PDO::prepare()`.

If you were to add it during the fetch, you need to do that before you append it onto `$rows[]` by adding it to the iterator/fetch variable `$selected_row`:

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Add an array key to the fetched row before calling array_map()
    // and appending to the $rows collection
    $selected_row['column'] = 'code1';
    $rows[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
}
```

Comment: I want to clarify which is the best solution?first one or second one?

Comment: I would personally prefer adding `code1` to the `SELECT` because you are treating it as part of the query result. It adds little overhead to the database query. Adding the value to the output array may make its origins less clear when you trace back later and forgot where it came from. But on the other hand perhaps someday someone will look at the database source table and be puzzled why that column isn't present. Neither solution is obviously superior, but I find the `SELECT` tidier. You could use it to replicate the same query result in SQL outside your application code too if needed.